# How can I control mpv in command line?

Tags: mpv

How can I control `mpv` in command line?

Like is there a `mpv next/prev` command that I can use to play next or previous media file?

Comment: mpv is a command-line program (for next and previous press < and > in the command-line while it's running). Are you wondered how to remote control it from another shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do such a thing:

- Setup IPC for mpv and socket controlling
- Using 3rd party scripts

#### Setup IPC for mpv

You can do such a thing with IPC, as `man mpv` said:

> Using --input-ipc-server is also suitable for purposes like remote control.

First you'll need to enable IPC socketing in your `mpv.conf` or `~/.config/mpv/mpv.conf`:

```bsh
# Enable the IPC support to control mpv from the command-line.
input-ipc-server=~~/socket
```

If you want to keep it open temporarily and only for one session, you can do:

```bsh
$ mpv --input-ipc-server=$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/mpv/socket
```

Now you can control your media:

##### Play / Pause

```bsh
echo cycle pause | socat - "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/mpv/socket"
```

##### Next Track

```bsh
echo playlist-next | socat - "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/mpv/socket"
```

##### Previous Track

```bsh
echo playlist-prev | socat - "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/mpv/socket"
```

#### Using an external program

Another way to control mpv from command line, is to use [`mpvc`](https://github.com/lwilletts/mpvc) or such programs, it's like `mpc` but for `mpv.

Really powerful, examples:

```bsh
$ mpvc next                   # Play next media
$ mpvc prev                   # Play previous media
$ mpvc mute                   # Mute media's sound track
$ mpvc unmute                 # Unmute media's sound track
$ mpvc volume +               # Increase volume
$ mpvc volume -               # Decrease volume
...
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options to interact with mpv from a command line, as suggested in the [manual](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#command-interface) e.g.,

- keybindings (using 'input.conf')
- OSD
- JSON IPC
- client API (libmpv) ...

In GNU systems you can check `/usr/share/doc/mpv/` to have some inspiration on how to configure mpv: `input.conf` has default keybindings and `mpv.conf`has an example configuration file.

You can check the manual to know about how to use in different operational systems:

https://mpv.io/manual/master/#command-interface

Answer (score 1):

While there are multiple ways and programs to handle controlling MPV from the command line, I wasn't satisfied with the existing solutions, so I wrote a script that supports controlling mpv from the command line in Python.

https://github.com/ideasman42/mpvctl/blob/master/mpvctl

---

```sh
$ mpvctl next               # Play next media
$ mpvctl prev               # Play previous media
$ mpvctl add *.mp3          # Play MP3's in the current directory.
$ mpvctl trash              # Move the file to the trash and play the next.
```

---

This supports:

- Basics such as pause/play, next/previous .. etc.
- Relative seeking.
- Adding file(s), optionally replacing the current playlist.
- Moving file playing to the trash.

The alternatives I found had some limitations (not expanding the `$PWD` when adding files - for example), and I found the BASH to handle more involved commands was difficult to follow. Hence the rewrite in Python.